# Centralização de DIV

Tags: css

Como faço para centralizar essas duas divs de baixo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
#content{
    position:relative;
    height: 80%;
    width: 85%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

#uphist{
    text-align: justify;
    padding-top: 2%;
    height:30%;
    width:80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#esqhist{
    background-color: red; /* EXCLUIR */
    height:60%;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#dirhist{
    background-color: aqua; /* EXCLUIR */
    text-align: justify;
    height:60%;
    width:30%;
    float:right;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Como você quer centralizar? Quer centralizar elas uma do lado da outra no meio, uma abaixo da outra ou uma sobre a outra?

Comment: Que as duas fiquem no meio uma ao lado da outra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, resolvi o problema coloca 'margin-left' e 'margin-right', continua o problema de não se adaptar a todos monitores, apenas ao meu, mas acredito que está seja uma questão não referente à está pergunta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
    #content{
        position:relative;
        height: 80%;
        width: 85%;
        margin-top: 1%;
    }

    #uphist{
        text-align: justify;
        padding-top: 2%;
        height:30%;
        width:80%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    #esqhist{
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: red; /* EXCLUIR */
        height:60%;
        width:50%;
        float:left;
        margin-left: 9%;
    }

    #dirhist{
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: aqua; /* EXCLUIR */
        text-align: justify;
        height:60%;
        width:30%;
        float:right;
        margin-right: 10%;
    }

    #imgmap{
        display: flex;
        margin: auto;
        width: 95%;
        height: 95%;
    }
```

```html
            <div id="content">
                <div id="uphist">
                    <h2>O Enredo:</h2>
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="esqhist">
                    <img src="imgs/mapa.png" id="imgmap" alt="mapa do reino de synph">
                </div>
                <div id="dirhist">
                    <h2>O Cenário:</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Segue ume exemplo para centralizar uma div na na vertical e horizontal:

```css
 .centro {
          position:absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          width:200px;
          height: 200px;
          margin-top: -100px;
          margin-left: -100px;
          border: solid 1px;
          background: grey;
  }
```

```html
<div class="centro"></div>
```

Agora pra centralizar numa div as duas colunas pode ser:

```css
.segura {
      max-width:800px;
      margin:auto;
      border: solid 1px;
      text-align: center;
  }

  .esq {
       display: inline-block;
       width:45%;
       border: solid 1px red;
       min-height: 250px;
   }
```

```html
<section class="segura">
  <div class="esq">
 Esquerda
  </div>
  <div class="esq">
 Direita
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz um exemplo para alinhar as divs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .divMain{
            width: 600px;
            height: 800px;
            background-color: black;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .divDireita{
            width: 40%;
            height: 30%;
            background-color: red;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .divEsquerda{
            width: 30%;
            height: 30%;
            background-color: blue;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="divMain">
        <div class="divDireita"></div>
        <div class="divEsquerda"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Explicando um pouco do código. Eu criei uma `div` com a classe `divMain`, essa `div` é a que irá alinhar os elementos dentro dela com o `text-align: center;`.

Como sugestão eu criaria uma `div` com essa propriedade com as duas `divs` dentro

Comment: Bom, como pode observar no meu código, estou utilizando 4 'divs', no caso uma será a 'div' que abriga todas as outras que seria a 'content' e as outras estão organizadas como up, esq, dir. O seu método já estou utilizando porém ele não resolve o problema da centralização, das duas 'divs' inferiores.

Comment: Tem como você postar o código Html também?

Comment: Inseri na outra resposta.